# Why does Print() in combination with reverse in Python produce None?

Tags: python, printing, reverse

I have just come across an interesting case, I think.

I was trying to reverse my list and then print output using the `print()` function.

Here are the two ways I have tried:

**1. Printing directly:**

```
x = [2.0, 9.1,12.5]
print(x.reverse())
```

output: `None`

**2. Using f string**:

```
x = [2.0, 9.1,12.5]
print(f"The reverse of x is {x.reverse()}")
```

output: `The reverse of x is None`

The output from both methods is `None` as you can see above.

Can anyone explaing why both methods produce `None`?

P.S. I know that the this method works and prints revered list

```
x.reverse()
print(x)
```

but I am not intereseted in this? I want to find out why both methods above produce `None`.

Comment: Reverse operates in-place and returns `None`. Use `x[::-1]` instead `x.reverse()`

Comment: the *reverse()* function implicitly returns None. The list will be modified *in situ*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x.reverse()` is a so called in-place operation, that means the list stored in the variable `x` is modified (reversed) and the output of `x.reverse()` is `None`. Hence, when you run `print(x.reverse())` it prints the output which in this case it `None`.

P.S.

If you need an operation which returns a reversed copy of the original list, you can use `reversed()` more info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
x = [2.0, 9.1, 12.5]
print(list(reversed(x)))
```

(Note: `list` is used to convert the iterator result of `reversed` to a list).

The second option is to create a reversed copy via [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) (thanks @Andrey):

```
x = [2.0, 9.1, 12.5]
print(x[::-1])
```

More context:

In general, in-place operations return `None`, that helps prevent mistakes and distinguish in-place and normal operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse and print it like this:

```py
print(x[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```py
x = [2.0, 9.1,12.5]
x.reverse()
print(x)
```

It should in theory work. Don't flame me if it doesn't I am quite new to stack overflow so I am not too sure on how to post answers and the sort.

Comment: You code works and I knew it before but it does not answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the list and print it by using the following code!

```py
# create a list 
mylist = [2.0, 9.1,12.5] 
x.reverse() # Reverse the list
print(mylist) # Print the list


# Output: [12.5, 9.1, 2.0]
```

Comment: This is definitely bad pattern! Atleast rename the function to `print_reversed_list()`.

Comment: ***It's not definitely bad pattern*** I made the function with that name, but it is also understandable.

Comment: If side-effect of the function is outside the scope of the functions with fixed variable name `x` its definitely bad pattern.

Comment: I made it x, so he can use the code instantly, even the asker can understand because he set the list to x

Comment: I understand, but teaching this way of thinking can be problematic in the long run (in other tasks, where side-effect can be hard to debug).

Comment: @mikulatomas What is the problem with x can u explain?

Comment: @G.T. `x` is variable outside so called *scope* of the function `print_reversed_list`. It CAN be dangerous to modify value/content of variable outside the function. The name is not the problem here (but also, I would prefer some more descriptive name). The good pattern would be to pass the list as *argument*, reverse it and return reversed list - then print it with `print()` function.

Comment: @G.T. You can see my answer below for more details.